# XDocument.Descendants() returns NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have some difficulties to retrieve some datas in my XML file.
This is what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<hexML version="0.9">
<head>
<title><![CDATA[Title ]]></title>
<description/>
<ftm date="2014-09-24T16:34:37 CET"/>
</head>
<body>
    <press_releases>
        <press_release id="1796257" language="fr" type="5">
            <published date="2014-06-19T11:55:09 CET"/>
            <categories>
            <category id="75" label="French" keywords="language"/>
            </categories>
            <headline><![CDATA[Test Release for Website 3]]></headline>
            <main><![CDATA[TEXT XML DETAILLE]]></main>
            <footer><![CDATA[]]></footer>
            <files>
                <file id="618383" format="pdf" type="Regular Attachment">
                <file_headline><![CDATA[Test Attachment]]></file_headline>
                <location><![CDATA[http://test.html1796257/618383.pdf]]></location>
                </file>
            </files>
            <location href="/S/151406/1796257.xml"/>
        </press_release>
    </press_releases>
</body>
</hexML>
```

i try to get this data : http://test.html1796257/618383.pdf (in the "files" tag)

This is what i tried so far :

```
            string Linkpdf = (from c in DetailXml.Descendants("files")                                  
                             select c.Element("location").Value).Single();
```

This returns me the exception mentionned above.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked with a debugger that `DetailXml` is not `null`?

Comment: Yes it is not null because i'm doing several linq to XML requests and only this one does not work...

Comment: Try swapping `Single` and `Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the XML was indented properly :

```
<files>
    <file id="618383" format="pdf" type="Regular Attachment">
        <file_headline><![CDATA[Test Attachment]]></file_headline>
        <location><![CDATA[http://test.html1796257/618383.pdf]]></location>
    </file>
</files>
```

you'll be able to see clearly that `<location>` is direct child of `<file>` element within `<files>` :

```
string Linkpdf = (from c in DetailXml.Descendants("files")
                  select c.Element("file").Element("location").Value).Single();
```